# Can I use SyntaxNet as a library from my C++ code?

Tags: syntaxnet

I'm writing a semantic analysis application written on C++ that is internally based on syntactic parses of sentences. SyntaxNet is used to provide required dependency trees, and it works quite well.
The only thing is that I have to call SyntaxNet as an external application with the following calling for every sentence that my application handles:

```
system("./syntaxnet/demo.sh");
```

I notice a remarkable time expenses with such method of using SyntaxNet and would like to know if it is possible to use SyntaxNet as a library with some programming language (preferably, C++) API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what about using Serving API?

https://github.com/dmansfield/parsey-mcparseface-api/issues/1

you can modify parsey_api.cc for loading exported model and parsing.

for python user, python client code 
https://github.com/dsindex/syntaxnet/blob/master/README_api.md